# Bootstrap Toggle Hidden Div and Input Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm using [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) to toggle the visibility of a div, this much I can do.

Within the div there are inputs, if there are *any* values in the inputs when the user toggles i'd like to prompt them with a 'are you sure you want to delete these values' box.

- If the user selects `ok`, I want to clear the input values and hide the div, i.e. reset everything to default.
- If the user selects `cancel` I want to do nothing, i.e. keep the div open and retain the current input values

I can't seem to get it working.

My code is below a here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/Lg9p417t/).

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value='1' name="test" id="test">
<hr>
<div id="advanced">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="one">
    <input type="text" name="two">
  </form>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function checkValues() {
  if ($('#advanced').find('input:text').val() !== '') {
    clearInput();
  }
}

function clearInput() {
  var txt;
  var r = confirm("You sure you want to remove these values?");
  if (r == true) {
    resetValues();
  } else {
    console.log('keep values and box open');
  }
}

function resetValues() {
  $('#advanced').find('input:text').val('');
}

$(function() {
  $('#test').bootstrapToggle({
    on: 'Hide',
    off: 'Show',
    onstyle: 'danger'
  });
  $("#advanced").hide();
  $('#test').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      checkValues();
      $("#advanced").show(500);
    }
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
      checkValues();
      $("#advanced").hide(500);
    }

  });
})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set some sort of flag that tells the system to only remove the values if the confirm dialog does not return false

```js
    function checkValues() {
      if ($('#advanced').find('input:text').val() !== '') {
        var state = clearInput();
        return state;
      }
    }

    function clearInput() {
      var txt;
      var r = confirm("You sure you want to remove these values?");
      if (r === true) {
        resetValues();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    function resetValues() {
      $('#advanced').find('input:text').val('');
    }

    $(function() {
      $('#test').bootstrapToggle({
        on: 'Hide',
        off: 'Show',
        onstyle: 'danger'
      });
      $("#advanced").hide();
      $('#test').change(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
          checkValues();
          $("#advanced").show(500);
        }
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
          state = checkValues();
          if(state != false){
              $("#advanced").hide(500);
          } else {
              $("#test").data('bs.toggle').on(true);
              // let the checkbox remain toggled
          }
          
        }

      });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<input type="checkbox" value='1' name="test" id="test">
<hr>
<div id="advanced">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="one">
    <input type="text" name="two">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Where did you find the `data('bs.toggle').on(true);` I couldn't see it in the docs anywhere and wasn't sure how to programmatically change the value of the toggle.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek You're welcome. Here is a good reference: https://github.com/minhur/bootstrap-toggle/issues/24

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
    function checkValues() {
  if ($('#advanced').find('input:text').val() !== '') {
    clearInput();
  } else {
    $("#advanced").hide();
  }
}

function clearInput() {
  var txt;
  var r = confirm("You sure you want to remove these values?");
  if (r == true) {
    resetValues();
    $("#advanced").hide(500);
  } else {
    $('#test').bootstrapToggle('on');
    console.log('keep values and box open');
  }
}

function resetValues() {
  $('#advanced').find('input:text').val('');
}

$(function() {
  $('#test').bootstrapToggle({
    on: 'Hide',
    off: 'Show',
    onstyle: 'danger'
  });
  $("#advanced").hide();
  $('#test').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      $("#advanced").show(500);
    }
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
      checkValues();
    }

  });
})
```

Here is the link [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg9p417t/70/)

Comment: Thanks @satheesh but this doesn't work. The `hide` button doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/Lg9p417t/64/

```js
$(function() {
  $('#test').bootstrapToggle({
    on: 'Hide',
    off: 'Show',
    onstyle: 'danger'
  });
  $("#advanced").hide();
  $('#test').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      if ($('#advanced').find('input:text').val() === '') {
        $('#advanced').find('input:text').val('');
      }
      $("#advanced").show(500);
    }
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
      if ($('#advanced').find('input:text').val() !== '') {
        var txt;
        var r = confirm("You sure you want to remove these values?");
        if (r == true) {
          $("#advanced").hide(500);
          $('#advanced').find('input:text').val('');
        } else {
          $('#test').bootstrapToggle('on');
        }
      } else {
        $("#advanced").hide(500);
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap2-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.4/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/master/console.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value='1' name="test" id="test">
<hr>
<div id="advanced">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="one">
    <input type="text" name="two">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Shiladitya but the `hide` button doesn't seem to work? When I click `show` the inputs appear, but when I click `hide`, they still remain?

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek I've updated the answer, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for that! Any chance you could add a simple explanation of where I was going wrong please?